ConstraintViolationException is trown even before actual save is called
Exception I get due to concurrency comes much before actual saveOrUpdate(entity) is called. What am I missing here ? Is it because @Transactional on my service class ? issue is I am catching exception in Facade but it seems it never enters there.
2024-04-23 18:52:00.125 ERROR [my.package.MyAdvice: qtp282850912-717] - Unknown exception stacktrace org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [SQL here]; constraint [Constraint name here]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch

            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:163)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:730)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:592)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:522)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:293)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672)
            at my.package.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55ad180f.save(<generated>)
            at my.package.MyController.save(MyController.java:100)
            at my.package.MyControllerApiIntf.save(MyControllerApiIntf.java:121)

I have following application flow
    @Controller
    public class MyController implements MyControllerApiIntf {
    
        @Autowired 
        MyService mySerivce;
    
        public void saveDate(Dto reqDto) {
    
           //covert ReqDto to entity object
           MyEntity entity = getEntity(reqDto);
    
           myService.save(entity)
        }
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public class MyService {
    
       @Autowired
       MyFacade myFacade;
    
       public void save(MyEntity entity) {
          myFacade.save(entity)   
       }
    
    }
    
    @Component
    public class MyFacade {
    
        public void saveNew(MyEntity entity) {
               try {
                  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
               } catch (ConstraintViolationException ce) {
                  //log here
               }
        }
     }

